# Alernative to close all for debugging purposes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to debug a script with memory problems. `close all` is resolving the problem. But I would like to find the place in the code where the problem is actually occurring. Is there an alternative to `close all` (like something that tells what `close all` is actually closing) to see what are the figures or else taking the most memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can close a specific figure by passing the figure handle to [`close`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html).

```
hFig1=figure;
hFig2=figure;

close(hFig1);
```

This will only close the first figure.

You can close your figures one by one while watching memory usage to understand which one is causing the problem.

Comment: There is over 300 figures, generated in different part of the code. Your approach could work, but it would take a really long time.

Comment: @m_power Yeah, it won't work. Do you really need all 300 figures to be on screen at the same time?

Comment: @m_power: If you close half your figures (by automatically generated script) and the problem goes away, it's likely to relate to the other half of figures. Divide that half into two quarters. Re-run closing only one quarter. Rinse and repeat, you will have the problematic figure in less than ten iterations. (this whole testing process is automatable, but may not be worth automating for just 10 iterations).

Comment: @HebeleHododo All the figures are set to visible 'off'.

Comment: @m_power I mean do you need them to be plotted and in memory?

Comment: @HebeleHododo The scripts and functions purpose is generating figures. All figures are saved in specific folders. I do use the 'close(gcf)' command after creating and saving a new figure.

Comment: @m_power Do you generate all figures and then save and close them?  It would be really helpful if you include more details in your question. This would increase your chances in getting a better and more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'whos' to see memory usage. See here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html

Comment: 'whos' only shows me what variable take more bytes. If i do a 'close all', whos will still show me the same thing.

Comment: maybe what you need is to store available memory as you keep plotting your figures. just call memory at various parts of the code and see where you lose the most memory.